# The new syntax for Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am struggling a bit to understand how the new AAA syntax works in Rhino Mocks. Most of my tests look like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        //Setup
        ISth sth= mocks.DynamicMock<ISth>();

        //Expectations
        Expect.Call(sth.A()).Return("sth");

        mocks.ReplayAll();
        //Execution
        FunctionBeingTested(sth);
        //...asserts, etc

        //Verification
        mocks.VerifyAll();
    }
```

How would it look like using AAA syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    ISth sth= MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISth>();

    sth
      .Stub(x => x.A())
      .Return("sth");

    // Act
    FunctionBeingTested(sth);

    // Assert
}
```

To really benefit from the new AAA syntax, you have to change your mind a bit. I try to explain.

There is a major difference in my proposal: there is no "Expect-Verify". So I propose to not expect the call, because there is a return value. I assume that the method can't pass the test when it didn't call `sth.A`, because it will miss the correct return value. It will fail at least one of the other asserts.

This is actually a good thing.

- you can move the Stub to TestInitialize, it does not hurt when the stubbed method is not called in a test (it's not an expectation). Your tests will become shorter.
- Your test does not know "how" the system under test does the job, you only check the results. Your tests will become more maintainable.

---

There is another scenario, where you actually need to check if a method had been called on the mock. Mainly if it returns void. For instance: an event should have been fired, the transaction committed and so on. Use `AssertWasCalled` for this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    ISth sth= MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISth>();

    // Act
    FunctionBeingTested(sth);

    // Assert
    sth
      .AssertWasCalled(x => x.A());
}
```

Note: there is not return value, so there is no Stub. This is an ideal case. Of course, you could have both, `Stub` and `AssertWasCalled`.

---

There is also `Expect` and `VerifyAllExpectations`, which actually behaves like the old syntax. I would only use them when you *need* `Stub` and `AssertWasCalled` in the same test, *and* you have complext argument constraints which you don't want to write twice. Normally, **avoid** `Expect` and `VerifyAllExpectations`

Answer (score 1):

example from Ayende`s blog:

```
[Test]
public void WhenUserForgetPasswordWillSendNotification_UsingExpect()
{
    var userRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUserRepository>();
    var notificationSender = MockRepository.GenerateMock<INotificationSender>();

    userRepository.Stub(x => x.GetUserById(5)).Return(new User { Id = 5, Name = "ayende" });
    notificationSender.Expect(x => x.Send(null)).Constraints(Text.StartsWith("Changed"));

    new LoginController(userRepository, notificationSender).ForgotMyPassword(5);

    notificationSender.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Changes in yours test

```
[Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var sth= MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISth>();  
        sth.Expect(x=>sth.A()).Return("sth");

        //Act
        FunctionBeingTested(sth);

        //Assert
        sth.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

But that's just a long shot. Wrote it as i suspect it to be.